Non-radiative decay rates computation
What is the most straightforward computational method to estimate the non-radiative decay rates in organic molecules? I have done TD-DFT calculations and really struggling to compute the rates.

Which organic molecules are you studying ? Which TD-DFT calculations have you done ?  Where is the problem ?

The usual way is to use the Fermi Golden Rule based on the vibrational energy levels and singlet-triplet spin orbit coupling / anharmonicity rather than from MO.

@Maurice, I am studying molecules like naphthalene and anthracene. My TD-DFT is performed on the gas phase of the molecule using Gaussian and levels of the theory discussed in recent literature.

@porphyrin, I would appreciate it if you could provide further explanations. I thought FGR is only for the radiative decay rate. Isn't it?

No not just for radiative process, there is a lot about non-radiate processes  in the literature but from the 1970's when most was worked out. See papers by Karl Freed, S.H. Lin, W. Siebrand, J. Jortner.
